# Ansible unable to unpack docker_compose module on remote host?

Tags: docker-compose, ansible

I'm trying to deploy a rustdesk server using Ansible's docker_compose module. I've never had issues before, but now it seems like Ansible is having trouble to 'deploy' its python modules onto the target host. Here's the complete error:

```
{
  "changed": false,
  "module_stderr": "Shared connection to ###### closed.\r\n",
  "module_stdout": "Traceback (most recent call last): 
File \"/home/####/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1686062468.971405-20881-241166903882758/AnsiballZ_docker_compose.py\", line 107, in <module> _ansiballz_main() 
File \"/home/####/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1686062468.971405-20881-241166903882758/AnsiballZ_docker_compose.py\", line 99, in _ansiballz_main
    invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)
  File \"/home/####/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1686062468.971405-20881-241166903882758/AnsiballZ_docker_compose.py\", line 47, in invoke_module
   runpy.run_module(mod_name='ansible_collections.community.docker.plugins.modules.docker_compose', init_globals=dict(_module_fqn='ansible_collections.community.docker.plugins.modules.docker_compose', _modlib_path=modlib_path),
  File \"/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py\", line 224, in run_module
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)
  File \"/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py\", line 96, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File \"/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py\", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_community.docker.docker_compose_payload_59n62rx6/ansible_community.docker.docker_compose_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/docker/plugins/modules/docker_compose.py\", line 1220, in <module>
  File \"/tmp/ansible_community.docker.docker_compose_payload_59n62rx6/ansible_community.docker.docker_compose_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/docker/plugins/modules/docker_compose.py\", line 1209, in main
  File \"/tmp/ansible_community.docker.docker_compose_payload_59n62rx6/ansible_community.docker.docker_compose_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/docker/plugins/modules/docker_compose.py\", line 728, in exec_module\r\nOSError: [Errno 39] Directory not empty: '/tmp/ansiblebfhv3gvw'\r\n",
  "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error",
  "rc": 1
}
```

The relevant error code seems to be: `OSError: [Errno 39] Directory not empty: '/tmp/ansiblebfhv3gvw`.

I have no idea how to fix this issue, I've tried rebooting and deleting /tmp but that didn't work. And also I couldn't find anyone having the same issue.

I've tried rebooting and deleting the /tmp folder with no success.